# sybase: how do I drop all tables, and stored procs if possible?

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to drop all tables and stored procedures in a schema, anyone know how to do this? I'd like to avoid dropping the entire database if possible.

Comment: Why not just drop the schema?  This sort of operation generally requires dynamic SQL to loop through lists

Comment: I wanted to avoid re-creating the users and custom types if I could. plus, I am just curious how this would be done, I can certainly drop/recreate if there's no great way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could iterate over the sysobjects table with a series of drops and systematically drop all the objects you want gone.

```
declare tables cursor 
for select name from sysobjects where type='U'
go
declare @name varchar(255)
open tables
fetch tables into @name
while (@@sqlstatus = 0)
begin
exec("drop table "+ @name)
fetch tables into @name
end
close tables
deallocate cursor tables
```

Yes that requires cursors and it's gonna be a bit slow but it should pretty much wipe the database clean.

- for tables you would need to have
  type='U' and use drop table in the
  loop
- for stored procesures you would
  have P or XP and use drop procedure
  in the loop

More information:

- [the sysobjects table specification](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables46.htm)
- [using cursors](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug768.htm)

Comment: I've almost got this working, the "drop table @name" part is giving me problems, and I had to add a "go" after the "declare" "for". I'll post my script as soon as I get it working and accept your answer, thanks for the help, this post was very educational for me.

Comment: Help is what stackoverflow is for :) I changed the above script to try and help you more. includes the missing "go" and the exec idiom to drop the trigger on a dynamic basis.

Comment: Jean, the exec did the trick. the script works for me, and wipes the database clean. I did %s/trigger/table/g.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
USE ban_des_rsp1
go
IF OBJECT_ID('rspman.sp_eliminar_base') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE rspman.sp_eliminar_base
    IF OBJECT_ID('rspman.sp_eliminar_base') IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING PROCEDURE rspman.sp_eliminar_base >>>'
    ELSE
        PRINT '<<< DROPPED PROCEDURE rspman.sp_eliminar_base >>>'
END
go
create proc rspman.sp_eliminar_base
as
declare @w_id int, @w_name varchar(255), @w_rowcount int, @w_sql varchar(2000)
select @w_id = 0

set rowcount 0
while (@w_id>=0)
begin

    set rowcount 1
    select @w_sql = 'alter table ' + object_name(tableid) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + object_name(constrid) 
    from sysconstraints

    select  @w_rowcount = @@rowcount
    if @w_rowcount<>1
    begin
        set @w_id = -1
    end
    else
    begin        
        exec(@w_sql)
    end


end

set rowcount 0
set @w_id = 0
while (@w_id>=0)
begin

    set rowcount 1
    select @w_id = id, @w_name =name 
    from sysobjects 
    where type = 'V'
      and id > @w_id
    order by id
    select  @w_rowcount = @@rowcount
    set rowcount 0

    if @w_rowcount<>1
        set @w_id = -1
    else
    begin        
        if (@w_name like 'gen%' or @w_name like 'vis%' )
        begin
            select @w_sql = 'drop view '  + @w_name
            exec(@w_sql)
        end
    end


end



set rowcount 0
set @w_id = 0
while (@w_id>=0)
begin

    set rowcount 1
    select @w_id = id, @w_name =name 
    from sysobjects 
    where type = 'U'
      and id > @w_id
    order by id
    select  @w_rowcount = @@rowcount
    set rowcount 0

    if @w_rowcount<>1
        set @w_id = -1
    else
    begin        
        select @w_sql = 'drop table '  + @w_name
        exec(@w_sql)
    end
end    

set rowcount 0
set @w_id = 0
while (@w_id>=0)
begin

    set rowcount 1
    select @w_id = id, @w_name =name 
    from sysobjects 
    where type = 'P'
      and id > @w_id
    order by id
    select  @w_rowcount = @@rowcount
    set rowcount 0

    if @w_rowcount<>1
        set @w_id = -1
    else
    begin        
        if @w_name like 'pro%'
        begin
            select @w_sql = 'drop proc '  + @w_name
            exec(@w_sql)
        end
    end



end
go
EXEC sp_procxmode 'rspman.sp_eliminar_base', 'unchained'
go
IF OBJECT_ID('rspman.sp_eliminar_base') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT '<<< CREATED PROCEDURE rspman.sp_eliminar_base >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< FAILED CREATING PROCEDURE rspman.sp_eliminar_base >>>'
go
```