# Dropping all tables in Sybase ASE including those with constraints

Tags: sap-ase

What is the best way to completely drop all tables in a database in Sybase ASE without dropping the database? I have been using a script: [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799673/sybase-how-do-i-drop-all-tables-and-stored-procs-if-possible) but I am getting errors trying to drop all tables in a database due to referential integrity.

In MySQL I could use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0`

Is there a way to do this in Sybase ASE or can the script above be extended to loop through the constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to drop constraints:

```
declare cur cursor 
for 
  select SOR.Name as constraint, SOT.Name as table
  from sysreferences SR
  join sysobjects SOR on SOR.id = SR.constrid 
  join sysconstraints SC on SC.constrid = SR.constrid
  join sysobjects SOT on SOT.id = SC.tableid
go
declare @constraint varchar(500)
declare @table varchar(500)
declare @SQL varchar(500)

open cur
fetch cur into @constraint,@table 
  while (@@sqlstatus = 0)
  begin

    select @SQL = 'alter table '+@table+' drop '+@constraint
    exec( @SQL)
    fetch cur into @constraint,@table 

  end
close cur
deallocate cursor cur
```

next you can drop tables.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to drop all constraints in the accepted answer did not work for me. Here is a modified version which works in my ASE16.

```
BEGIN
declare cur cursor 
for 
  select o.name, t.name from sysreferences r
  join sysobjects o on o.id = r.constrid 
  join sysconstraints c on c.constrid = r.constrid
  join sysobjects t on t.id = c.tableid
END
GO
--
declare @constraint varchar(500)
declare @table varchar(500)
declare @SQL varchar(500)
--
open cur
fetch cur into @constraint,@table 
  while (@@sqlstatus = 0)
  begin
    --
    select @SQL = 'alter table '+@table+' drop constraint '+@constraint
    exec( @SQL)
    fetch cur into @constraint,@table 
    --
  end
close cur
deallocate cursor cur
```

Answer (score 0):

the above logic is correct but the query is wrong and you might get issues with the "constraint" and "table" keywords.

1. use something like constriantName and tableName in line 3
2. The query is missing "constraint", correct query:
   'alter table ' + @table + ' drop constraint ' +@constraint